# How to wire up a button's Tap event to an event handler in NativeScript?

Tags: typescript, user-interface, nativescript, code-behind

I'm having a tough time jump starting into NativeScript.
I understand the UI side pretty well with the XML-type tags to implement UI elements.
But I'm unsure of the syntax on how to turn my UI into an actual functional program in the code behind.

For example, if I have the following button in my app, I'm not sure of the syntax to wire up an event handler for the Tap event:

```
<Page loaded="pageLoaded" class="page" xmlns="http://www.nativescript.org/tns.xsd">

<ActionBar title="Home" class="action-bar">
</ActionBar>

<TabView>
    <TabViewItem title="Tab 1">
        <StackLayout>
            <Button id="btn_Woohoo" text="Button WooHoo" tap="btn_woohoo_tap" />
        </StackLayout>
    </TabViewItem>
    <TabViewItem title="Tab 2">

    </TabViewItem>
</TabView>
```

I've seen a few different syntactical implementations such as:

```
1) tap="methodName"
2) tap="{{ methodName }}"
3) {tap}="methodName"
4) {tap}="{{ methodName }}"
5) tap="methodName()"
```

None of these implementations are explained where I saw them, nor do they work when I try them.

In the code behind, I've tried a few different syntactical ways to write up the event handler method, but none seemed to work for me either.

Here's my current implementation:

```
export function btn_woohoo_tap(args: EventData) {
    //alert("Woohoo!");
    //btn_Woohoo.text
    //let woohooButton = this.getViewById('btn_Woohoo');
    //woohooButton.text = "test";
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This should work, if you still have issues please share a Playground sample where the issue can be reproduced.

**XML**

```
<Button id="btn_Woohoo" text="Button WooHoo" tap="btn_woohoo_tap" />
```

**TS**

```
export function btn_woohoo_tap(args: EventData) {

}
```

Another possible syntax is `tap="{{ btn_woohoo_tap }}"`, which means the function is binding from ViewModel not from code behind file. [Here you find the relevant docs](https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/data-binding#binding-to-an-event-in-xml). I don't think rest of the syntaxes in your question are valid.

Comment: Thank you. And just curious, what's the purpose of the "export" keyword I keep seeing prior the function keyword?

Comment: It's the TypeScript syntax for the JavaScript equivalent - `exports.btn_woohoo_tap = function(args) { ... }`. Event listeners must be exported from JS file in order to work.